# Where/when/why is the first array element dropping?

Tags: javascript

My assignment is to have a text box that accepts user input, pushes that input into an array, then based on the status of a checkbox examines a hard coded array in order to evaluate whether the user input elements match with the hard coded array elements.

In the basic case, where the strings must match exactly (based on case sensitivity), my code agrees with words that do match, and ignores words that don't match. I add the matched words to a string, then display the string in an alert.

HOWEVER: in the second case, where the strings are intended to ignore case sensitivity (so the user can enter in any combination of upper and lower case) my alert displaying the list of matched names is always dropping the FIRST word entered in the user input text box. The case sensitivity logic appears to be working fine - the problem is that one of the words is being dropped.

Here is my code first for the HTML shell

```js
function process() {

//create string to store user input
var s = document.getElementById("inputTextBox").value;

//testing text area to display captured input
document.getElementById("textArea").value = s;

//create array to store user input
var inputArray = [];

//create array of names to check user input against
var namesArray = ["John", "Bill", "Mary", "Ted", "Roger"];

//split the string by spaces
var input = s.split(" ");

//put the split string into the inputArray
inputArray = s.split(" ");

//determine length of arrays
var inputArrayLength = inputArray.length;
var nameArrayLength = namesArray.length;

//create string to hold matched names
var matchedNames = "";

for(var i = 0; i < inputArrayLength; i++)
{
    //set current name string to current array element
    currName = inputArray[i];

    //first determine if the checkbox IS checked
    if ((document.getElementById("checkBox").checked) == true)
    {
        //if it is checked, determine if currName == name in namesArray
        if (currName == 'John' || currName == 'Bill' || currName == 'Mary' || currName == 'Ted' || currName == 'Roger')
        {
            matchedNames = matchedNames.concat(currName + " ");
        }}

    //if it is NOT checked
    else if ((document.getElementById("checkBox").checked) == false)
    {
        //traverse array and toLowerCase all elements
        for (var j = 0; j < inputArrayLength; j++)
        {
            inputArray[j] = inputArray[j].toLowerCase();
        }

        //then determine if toLowerCase string is present in array
        if (currName == 'john' || currName == 'bill' || currName == 'mary' || currName == 'ted' || currName == 'roger')
        {
            matchedNames = matchedNames.concat(currName + " ");
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("textArea").value = matchedNames;

//alert matched names
alert("Matched Names: " + matchedNames + ".");
}
```

```html
<label>Please enter a series of first names, separated by spaces</label>
<br />
<input id="inputTextBox" type="text" name="textBox1" style="width: 200px;"/>
<br />
<label><input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />toggle case sensitivity</label>
<br />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Process" onclick="process();"/>
<br />
<textarea id="textArea" name="textArea1" rows="2" cols="1" style="width: 400px;"></textarea>
```

I am aware there are many stylistic problems (crappy names), some serious redundancy, and that this could probably be tightened up logically to use less lines and etc.

Answer (score 1):

> this could probably be tightened up logically to use less lines

Logic is basically the source of your problems. You have a loop to test each `currName`. Inside the loop, you check whether the checkbox is checked, and if it is not, you lowercase the input array; but the first `currName` was taken out of it before lowercasing. So if you enter `John Mary Bill`, you will be comparing the non-lowercased `John` and then the lowercased `mary` and `bill`. The non-lowercased `John` obviously does not equal `john`. Additionally, the lowercasing of the whole array happens for each element of the array, which is adding an unnecessary exponential complexity to the code (i.e. unnecessarily inefficient).

It would be much easier to just lowercase the input string at the very start (before the loop, before the split, even):

```
if (caseSensitive) {
  s = s.toLowerCase();
}
var input = s.split(" ");
```

or at least to lowercase each `currName` as it is being taken out of the array:

```
var origCurrName = inputArray[i];
var currName = origCurrName;
if (caseSensitive) {
  currName = currName.toLowerCase();
}
```

Some further notes:

- You don't have to test whether something is `true`; the `if` condition will trigger on the expression being truthy (which `true` is, and `false` is not).
- If you know there to be only two options (like truthy and falsy, checked and unchecked), you do not need to use `else if`, a simple `else` will suffice
- You never use the variable `input`
- Taking `caseSensitive` before the loop is more efficient and does lots to improve your code legibility... if only you would have used it :)

EDIT: Derp, in scrolling, I mistook Phil's `var caseSensitive...` line for yours. Apologies to both Phil and OP.

Comment: thank you for the very useful answer! lots for me to think about. i really appreciate your time and energy.

Answer (score 1):

during the matching process in the second case, you haven't converted the `currName` to lowercase.
So you can just do `currName.toLowerCase() == "john"` and so on..

Comment: thank you for your answer! i appreciate your time and energy.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is that you convert the `inputArray` to lowercase in the first iteration of the loop but you do not convert `currName` which is still the original value.

On subsequent iterations, `currName` is pulled from the now lowercased array so they match correctly.

In any case, here's a much simpler method using `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.indexOf`

```js
//create array of names to check user input against
var namesArray = ["John", "Bill", "Mary", "Ted", "Roger"];
var lowerCaseNamesArray = namesArray.map(name => name.toLowerCase())

function process() {

  //create string to store user input
  var s = document.getElementById("inputTextBox").value;

  // are we doing case-sensitive checks
  var caseSensitive = document.getElementById("checkBox").checked;
  if (!caseSensitive) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
  }

  //create array to store user input
  var inputArray = s.split(" ");
  
  // which array should we check?
  var checkArray = caseSensitive ? namesArray : lowerCaseNamesArray;
  
  var matchedNames = inputArray.filter(function(currName) {
    return checkArray.indexOf(nameToCheck) !== -1;
  });

  document.getElementById("textArea").value = matchedNames.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<label>Please enter a series of first names, separated by spaces</label>
<br />
<input id="inputTextBox" type="text" name="textBox1" style="width: 200px;" />
<br />
<label><input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" />toggle case sensitivity</label>
<br />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Process" onclick="process();" />
<br />
<textarea id="textArea" name="textArea1" rows="2" cols="1" style="width: 400px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you for your time and energy! i really appreciate it.